# How to replicate gatsbyjs filter and search, like the one they have for their starters page?

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, graphql, gatsby

I want to build a search page that lets user query data based on certain criteria that they can choose from select and radio checkboxes, on behalf of which a query string is generated that gives the key/value pair for searching, the functionality is somewhat similar to what they have for their staters page.

Please check the link below to get an idea of what I am looking for:

- https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/?v=2      <----    query string.

These pages need to be shareable so query strings are essential and data fetching need be as quick as it is on their website.

From what I have understood so far, according to documentation:

- https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/data-fetching

I have two options:

- Get data during build time
- Get data during run time

For a run time, I think, I would need to use redux-thunk to make network calls to an ExpressJs, MongoDB REST API but my concern is that it can be slow.

For build time, I am sure on how can I source data from Graphql queries, and render them.

Any help on this will be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gatsby Starters Library is parsing the URL param in [this `urlToSearch` method](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/5b35accd289c4da6fc7ee515ba654ee3985f90f0/www/src/components/plugin-searchbar-body.js#L449-L456) in the `PluginSearchBar` component:

```js
urlToSearch = () => {
  if (this.props.location.search) { // get the params from the location prop
    const match = /(\?|&)=([^&]+)/.exec(this.props.location.search)
    if (match) return decodeURIComponent(match[2])
    return ``
  }
  return ``
}
```

Mainly, it uses the Gatsby [location prop](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/location-data-from-props/) (from `@reach/router` under the hood) to get the search keyword from the query string.

Search is then implemented client-side using Algolia's [react-instantsearch](https://github.com/algolia/react-instantsearch/) library. You can find the complete implementation in [plugin-searchbar-body.js](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/5b35accd289c4da6fc7ee515ba654ee3985f90f0/www/src/components/plugin-searchbar-body.js).

There are naturally other ways to implement search. A good place to start for inspiration is Gatsby's [Adding Search](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-search/) documentation.